Swing components not rendering properly as expected when Migrated from java8 to java17
This is the sample code I have written to check the working of swing components When We are migrating from java8 to java17
When I set my display resolution to 1920X1200 and scaling as 150%(Recommended), in java8 all components are rendering properly, but If I run same code in java17 I am seeing some issues such as text stripping and in some cases they were overlapping
Can someone please suggest the solution for this problem.
public class Swing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3,3,3,3));
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField f1 = new JTextField(30);
        panel1.add(f1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("OK");
        panel1.add(button1, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3,3,3,3));
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField f2 = new JTextField(30);
        panel2.add(f2,BorderLayout.WEST);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Cancel");
        panel2.add(button2,BorderLayout.EAST);

        mainPanel.add(panel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(panel2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    
    }   
    );
}
}

These were the outputs for the above code in java8 and java17
Java8 Result
java17 Result

From Java 9 onward, Swing uses the Windows default display scaling.  If you want to change the default scaling, place this line System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1");
as the first line of your Swing application.
